# How to deal with anonymous edit spam

Tags: discussion

I guess the mods have noticed a lot of spam on this post https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/918/295

Is this occurring on any other posts? How can we deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are still getting spam after multiple rejects, then please follow this post [What can I do when a post I've written receives a lot of spam edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228789/what-can-i-do-when-a-post-ive-written-receives-a-lot-of-spam-edits)

> If that's the case, [contact the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) team with the following
>   information:
>
> ```
> *The URL of the post (be it question or answer), just copy the 'share' link under the post to obtain this.
> *How long this has been happening (so we can better scope a query)
> ```

I have already reported https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/918/295, so there is no need to do so again unless the spam keeps up.